# Ignore Errors During SetInterval Function and Just Continue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a very simple Javascript program running in node that pulls data from a websites API every minute, parses it, and displays it on the console.

The structure looks like this: (**UPDATED**)

```
var getData = function() {
  try {
    http.get(
      {"host": "api.coindesk.com", "path": "/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"},
      function(response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) {
          body += d;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
          var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(parsed.time.updatedISO + "   :::   $" + parsed.bpi.USD.rate_float);
        });
      }
    );
  } catch(error) {
    // Don't care if it fails, just wait and get the next minutes data
    console.log(error);
  }
}

SetInterval(getData, 60000);
```

When an error is thrown due to the connection or a parsing error, the entire programs stops, I need it to just ignore that error and try again in 60 seconds. I don't care if I miss a minute of data, I just need it to keep running.

Example Error:

```
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.coindesk.com api.coindesk.com:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:26)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It stops because you `return` from within the `catch` block. Remove the `return` keyword, and it will keep running.

```js
var getData = function() {
  try {
    // Retrieve and parse data
    throw Error("error");
    console.log("The parsed data");
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

setInterval(getData, 1000);
```

Comment: It's apparently not just "an error" but something to do with the errors it is throwing, because using that and throwing my own error inside the try block didn't cause it, but connection errors still do. I added the remaining code and an example of the error I get when connection is lost. (Originally I was going for the minimal functional code thing, but apparently it's more than that).

Comment: @FatalKeystroke -- the error you're trying to mention here is actually a rejected promise/asynchronous call. Try setting a callback on error for the `http.get` call, and throw a custom error from it. I am not much familiar about the syntax, but you should be able to search for it and implement.